# Log/Save domain users login/logout time on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain, logging

My idea is to make log-in and log-out scripts to capture the login/logout time and save it
 to a file (or into a Database). I have no idea how to capture the time.

Comment: I found this [script](http://slingfive.com/pages/code/bgInfo_scripts/scripts/getCurrentUserLastLoginTime.vbs) to capture the local machine last logon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest thing to do - that I would do to collect the most potentially relevant information - is to create batch scripts with the following lines (and place the batch scripts in Group Policy logon and logoff scripts - with .cmd extensions)

for logon:

**echo %username% logged on from %computername% on %date% at %time%>>\server\share\logon.log**

and for logout:

**echo %username% logged off from %computername% on %date% at %time%>>\server\share\logoff.log**

(You can use the same file and don't need to separate them, but for convenience, I split them into two files).

The above should append a line to the files logon.log or logoff.log (as appropriate) with the user's account name, the computer that the user logged in from, and the date and time.

By opening the file in excel and using the text-to-columns feature, you can easily create sortable reports.  (And you can leave off the text simplifying the logged data into something like **echo %username%,%computername%,%date%,%time%**)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using BAT, then just use `time /t`. Easy as cake.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to do this with scripts you can easily assign a VBS script to be run on logon in either Active Directory or Group Policy and just write login time, server name and user to a SQL Database.

Comment: Thanks. But, Which other way can i use for that goal? (without the scripts)

Comment: Luigi, in your question you clearly state that you want to achieve this via scripts.

Comment: Yes, and i continue with the idea. But if there is a more efficient way to do it, I'll do it.

Answer (score -3):

your script is wrong

```
echo %username% logged off from %computername% on %date% at %time%>>\server\share\logoff.log
```

this one right script

```
echo %username% logged off from %computername% on %date% at %time%>>\\server\share\logoff.log
```

your script is wrong

```
echo %username% logged on from %computername% on %date% at %time%>>\server\share\logon.log
```

this one right script

```
echo %username% logged on from %computername% on %date% at %time%>>\\server\share\logon.log
```